# Xamppp No Mcrypt.ini when intalling Lavarel

Tags: php, xampp

I tried to install Laravel on Xubuntu 14.04

I searched for every method, [they all  go like this](http://www.pannix.net/721/ubuntu_php_problem_json_and_mcrypt_missing_in_action/). By the way, I tried installing php and apache without xampp and didn't as well so it's not about xampp, I just went for xampp because it can easily be shut down, my laptop freezes on shut down if apache is working in background. Xampp is easier to work with.

mcrypt is enabled in php.ini, I did `aptitude install php5-mcrypt mcrypt` and tried `apt-get` as well. In fact I installed `aptitude` just because some SO user said it would work with `aptitude`.

After days and days of trying, I can safely say, `mcrypt.ini` does not exist on my computer, reinstalled again and again, the problem is still there. `whereis mcrypt.ini` gives nothing, Catfish couldn't find it too (Catfish was able to find php.ini)

Locate command doesn't return anything

So I can safely say, that file is missing, how do I obtain it?

Comment: Would anyone share his mcrypt.ini? Maybe it would work

Comment: I teied installing php-mcrypt on my debian wheezy vps and it worked easily, all I did is using apt-get. Didn't even edit php.uni, strange things happening!

Comment: Download the .deb file of mcrypt for Xubuntu 14.04 from www.ubuntu.com at [this link](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/mcrypt). The linked webpage says Ubuntu, but Xubuntu also has the Ubuntu Software Center in it, so it should be OK. Please comment if you need additional help.

Comment: I think this questions should not have been migrated because future releases are not in the [scope](http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) of this website.

Comment: @karel  what about php5-mcrypt

Comment: @OrangeTux why not? it clearly has something to do with ubuntu, on debian it works like a charm

Comment: @Fischer , did you solve your problem? I am suffering from the same bug.

Comment: @Paulocoghi nope, I got tired of it, and you know what I do when I get tired of something? I accept the question just to forget about it, I uninstalled php from ubuntu, and I now develop on my debian vps, I use sublimeSFTP, so all the files are edited on my pc, they are uploaded to my vps through sftp and there everything work perfectly, no longer working on localhost, I gave up on php and on ubuntu my friend, considering the possibility to migrate to manjaro in few weeks, a new world, many problems shall be gone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the .deb file of mcrypt for Xubuntu 14.04 from www.ubuntu.com at [this link](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/mcrypt). The linked webpage says Ubuntu, but Xubuntu also has the Ubuntu Software Center in it, so it should be OK. Download the .deb file of php5-mcrypt (MCrypt module for php5) for Xubuntu 14.04 from www.ubuntu.com at [this link](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/php5-mcrypt).

In case you want to verify these files after you download them with GtkHash or from the terminal, you can also get the checksum hashes of these .deb files at the same links at the bottom of the page. Please comment if you need additional help.

Comment: problem not solved yet, I'll spend more time on it in the weekend, maybe reinstall php and remove xampp but hey at least there's now mcrypt.ini, the file is there! so at least the .deb file you gave me are the ones I should use

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this `sudo php5enmod mcrypt` and check mcrypt using `php --ini` and on php console `php -a` execute a true: `var_dump(mcrypt_create_iv())`

Comment: after having followed your instructions, laravel seems to be installed, i don't see any mcrypt errors. however i see this http://pastebin.com/bhLb7EaE is this okay? or is it an error I need to worry about

Comment: PHP can works fine, but if you want fix errors shown on paste bin follow this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21257589/ubuntu-typing-php-in-terminal-shows-a-lot-of-errors I remembered that I fixed using `sudo apt-get remove php5-snmp`